# subscript out of bounds - R

Tags: r, instagram-api

I want to connect to the instagram API and getting data by R. I got `subscript out of bounds` error at the end. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks

```
app_name<-"HamidTT"
client_id<-"xxx"
client_secret<-"xxx"
scope="public_content"
instagram <- oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",access = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token")  
myapp <- oauth_app(app_name, client_id, client_secret)
ig_oauth <- oauth2.0_token(instagram, myapp,scope="public_content",  type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",cache=FALSE)

# Waiting for authentication in browser...
# Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
# Authentication complete.

tmp <- strsplit(toString(names(ig_oauth$credentials)), '"')
token <- tmp[[1]][4]
username<-"hrouhani"
user_info <- fromJSON(getURL(paste('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=',username,'&access_token=',token,sep="")),unexpected.escape = "keep")

user_info

# $meta
# $meta$code
# [1] 200

# $data
# list()

received_profile <- user_info$data[[1]]
# **Error in user_info$data[[1]] : subscript out of bounds**
```

Comment: It appears the user you searched for returned no data, hence the `list()` in `user_info$data`

Comment: When you put R code on SO please do not include the > and + from the output console. This makes it hard to run your code.

Comment: @emilliman5 i use another account . results are the same